# Using MySQL in Pydev Eclipse

Tags: python, mysql, eclipse, pydev, mysql-python

I am trying to access a MySQL database with python through Pydev Eclipse. I have installed the necessary files to access MysQL from python and I can access the database only when I write code in Python IDLE environment and run it from command prompt. However I am not able to run my applications from Pydev.

when I use this "import MysqlDB"  i get an error, but in IDLE no errors and my code runs very smoothly.
Does anyone know were the problem is?
Thanks

Comment: How did you install the python MysqlDB package and in Eclipse Preferences->Pydev->interpreter - Python what is the System libs value

Comment: solved,
Although I am using windows,I added MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.6-linux-i686.egg to the libraries in pyDev Eclipse and solved the problem.

Comment: Had this problem -oh!- 5 years later. How can you find the corresponding MYSQL_python egg file in your computer?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this same problem and found this link which helped me resolve it.  https://bohr.wlu.ca/cp363/notes/implementation/connectingPython.php

From there I was able to import mysql.connector and connect to the database installed on my localhost

```py
import mysql.connector
import getpass

pswd = getpass.getpass(prompt='Enter database password for root user:')
dbCnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password=pswd)
```

[image: Here is a screen shot of how I was able to execute the pip install]

Answer (score 0):

If the connector works in the IDLE but not in PyDev. Open Eclipse preferences, open PyDev directory and go to interpreter screen. Remove the interpreter and add it again from the location on your computer (Usually C drive). Close and reload Eclipse and now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Posting Answer in case URL changed in future

From Eclipse, choose Window / Preferences / PyDev / Interpreters / Python Interpreter, click on Manage with pip and enter the command:

install mysql-connector-python